Is it possible to display a component's name in a tooltip when hovering over it in the APS Viewer?
I'm trying to display the component name as a tooltip when hovering over it in the APS Viewer. I can retrieve the dbId using the OBJECT_UNDER_MOUSE_CHANGED event, but I haven't figured out how to display this as a tooltip. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

If you prefer to use the Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_UNDER_MOUSE_CHANGED event,
Except for listening to this event, you must implement the tooltip using Web technologies (e.g. HTML5, JavaScript and CSS).
Here is an example for this:
//aps-object-tooltip.js

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
// Written by Developer Advocacy and Support
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM 'AS IS' AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ObjectSensorTooltip extends THREE.EventDispatcher {
    constructor(parent) {
        super();

        this.parent = parent;
        this.init();
    }

    get viewer() {
        return this.parent.viewer;
    }

    init() {
        const container = document.createElement('div');
        container.classList.add('aps-object-sensor-tooltip');
        this.container = container;

        const bodyContainer = document.createElement('div');
        bodyContainer.classList.add('aps-object-sensor-tooltip-body');
        container.appendChild(bodyContainer);
        this.bodyContainer = bodyContainer;

        bodyContainer.innerHTML = 'No Data';

        this.viewer.container.appendChild(container);
    }

    setVisible(visible) {
        if (visible) {
            this.bodyContainer.classList.add('visible');
        } else {
            this.bodyContainer.classList.remove('visible');
        }
    }

    setPosition(point) {
        const contentRect = this.bodyContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
        const offsetX = contentRect.width / 2;
        const offsetY = contentRect.height + 0.7 * 24 / this.viewer.getWindow().devicePixelRatio;

        const pos = new THREE.Vector3(
            point.x - offsetX,
            point.y - offsetY,
            0
        );

        this.container.style.transform = `translate3d(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px, ${pos.z}px)`;
    }

    setPositionByWordPoint(point) {
        this.setPosition(this.viewer.worldToClient(point));
    }

    async getPropertiesAsync(dbId, model) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            model.getProperties2(
                dbId,
                (result) => resolve(result),
                (error) => reject(error)
            );
        });
    };

    getObjectBoundingBox(dbId, model) {
        const it = model.getInstanceTree();
        const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
        let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

        it.enumNodeFragments(dbId, (fragId) => {
            let box = new THREE.Box3();
            fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, box);
            bounds.union(box);
        }, true);

        return bounds;
    }

    async show(dbId, model) {
        if (!dbId || !model) return;

        this.bodyContainer.innerHTML = '';

        const nameSpan = document.createElement('span');
        nameSpan.classList.add('aps-object-sensor-tooltip-name');
        this.bodyContainer.appendChild(nameSpan);

        const props = await this.getPropertiesAsync(dbId, model);
        let nameString = 'Unknown';
        if (props) {
            nameString = props.name;
        }
        nameSpan.innerHTML = nameString;

        let bbox = this.getObjectBoundingBox(dbId, model);
        let position = bbox.getCenter();

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setPosition(this.viewer.worldToClient(position));
    }

    hide() {
        this.bodyContainer.innerHTML = 'No Data';
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

    destroy() {
        if (!this.container) return;

        this.bodyContainer.innerHTML = '';
        this.container.innerHTML = '';

        this.viewer.container.removeChild(this.container);

        delete this.bodyContainer;
        delete this.container;
    }
}

class ObjectTooltipExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);

        this.uiCreated = false;

        this.onHoveredObjectChangedHandler = this.onHoveredObjectChangedHandler.bind(this);
        this.createUI = this.createUI.bind(this);
    }

    onToolbarCreated() {
        if (!this.uiCreated)
            this.createUI();
    }

    onHoveredObjectChangedHandler(event) {
        console.log(event);

        if (event.dbId == -1) {
            this.tooltip.hide();
            return; //!<<< Do nothing when no object is under current mouse cursor.
        }

        let model = this.viewer.model;
        if (event.modelId != -1) {
            model = this.viewer.getAllModels().find(md => md.id == event.modelId);
        }

        this.tooltip.show(event.dbId, model);
    }

    createUI() {
        if (this.uiCreated) return;

        this.uiCreated = true;

        const tooltip = new ObjectSensorTooltip(this);
        this.tooltip = tooltip;
    }

    async load() {
        await this.viewer.waitForLoadDone();

        this.viewer.addEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_UNDER_MOUSE_CHANGED,
            this.onHoveredObjectChangedHandler
        );

        console.log('`ObjectTooltipExtension` has been loaded');

        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        this.viewer.removedEventListener(
            Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_UNDER_MOUSE_CHANGED,
            this.onHoveredObjectChangedHandler
        );

        this.tooltip.destroy();
        delete this.tooltip;
        this.tooltip = null;

        this.uiCreated = false;

        console.log('`ObjectTooltipExtension` has been unloaded');
        return true;
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('ObjectTooltipExtension', ObjectTooltipExtension);

/* aps-object-tooltip.css */

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Copyright (c) Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved
// Written by Developer Advocacy and Support
//
// Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in
// object code form for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted,
// provided that the above copyright notice appears in all copies and
// that both that copyright notice and the limited warranty and
// restricted rights notice below appear in all supporting
// documentation.
//
// AUTODESK PROVIDES THIS PROGRAM 'AS IS' AND WITH ALL FAULTS.
// AUTODESK SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTY OF
// MERCHANTABILITY OR FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR USE.  AUTODESK, INC.
// DOES NOT WARRANT THAT THE OPERATION OF THE PROGRAM WILL BE
// UNINTERRUPTED OR ERROR FREE.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 **/

/** Object Tooltip **/
/*https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip*/
.aps-object-sensor-tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 170px;
  }
  
  .aps-object-sensor-tooltip .aps-object-sensor-tooltip-body {
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -85px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  .aps-object-sensor-tooltip .aps-object-sensor-tooltip-body::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  }
  
  .aps-object-sensor-tooltip .aps-object-sensor-tooltip-body.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .aps-object-sensor-tooltip-name {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
  }
  
  .aps-object-sensor-tooltip-value {
    font-size: 13px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

Demo


Thanks @Eason Kang, for the information. I will test and let you know.
